# Customizing the width of twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how i can change the twitter bootstrap container width from 940 pixel to 1024 pixel by keeping it responsive and how i can change the span width for example by default the span1 width is 60px and how i can change it to 70 pixel.
can we change these without using LESS??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to: [Customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Scroll down to Container sizes, there you can change the Container size.

Take a look at everything, you can change nearly everything there. After you made the changes, you can download your custom build.

Answer (score 0):

you can change all of this on http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ without having to fool around  with less/css.